# docker swarm nfs volume not showing all directories

Tags: docker, nfs, docker-swarm

I've hit a wall with trying to figure this out.  I'm running docker swarm on two nodes and I created an nfs volume to my synology.

Inside of the container:

```
root@container:/data# ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:59 unprocessed
```

which is missing directories.  If I ssh into the host and check the docker mount there, I see this:

```
root@box:/var/lib/docker/volumes/vol_multimedia/_data# ls -ltr
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 1024 users  0 Sep  6  2021  images
drwxrwxrwx 1 1024 users 38 Dec 19  2021  unprocessed
drwxrwxrwx 1 1024 users 66 Apr  1 08:39  processed
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1026 users 41 May 29 23:21  multimedia-readme.txt
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 Jun  3 22:47 '#recycle'
```

which is what I expect to see.  Why would there only be a subset of files visible from within the docker container?

The docker command i used to create the volume is

```
docker volume create --driver local \
  --opt type=nfs \
  --opt o=addr=synology.local,rw,soft,nfsvers=4 \
  --opt device=:/volume1/multimedia \
  vol_multimedia
```

compose file looks like

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  jellyfin:
    # ... removed for brevity
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: vol_multimedia
        target: /data
    # ... removed for brevity

volumes:
  vol_multimedia:
    external: true
```

**UPDATE: What I had above seems to be misleading.  The container which was bad was running on a different node of the same swarm.  One node is correct but the other isn't.  Very bizarre two nodes in the same swarm would behave differently.**

Answer (score 1):

I never got this working.  I ended up mounting the NFS share on the host and doing a bind volume.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/524871)

Comment: I'm the author.  are you suggesting i move my "answer" to a comment under my question? @mforsetti